# tic tac toe for python3

Tags: python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

how do I add a score counter to this tic tac toe game:

i need to be able to keep score of the tic tac toe games so that the users (its a 2 player game) can play mutable games in a row and the program will keep score for them.The program bellow already allows the users to continue to play so that they can play multiple games in a row however the program does not keep track of the score of player x and o or the number of ties. how to I add to this so that it will tray player x's wins, player o's wins, and the number on ties

```
def drawboard(board):
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + str(board[7]) + ' | ' +str( board[8]) + ' | ' + str(board[9]))
    print('   |   |')
    print('-----------')
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + str(board[4]) + ' | ' + str(board[5]) + ' | ' + str(board[6]))
    print('   |   |')
    print('-----------')
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + str(board[1]) + ' | ' + str(board[2]) + ' | ' + str(board[3]))
    print('   |   |')
def draw(board):
    print(board[7], board[8], board[9])
    print(board[4], board[5], board[6])
    print(board[1], board[2], board[3])
    print()
def t(board):
    while True:
            try:
                    x = int(input())
                    if x in board:
                            return x
                    else:
                            print("\nSpace already taken. Try again")
            except ValueError:
                    print("\nThat's not a number. enter a space 1-9")
def GO(win,board):
    for x, o, b in win:
            if board[x] == board[o] == board[b]:
                    print("Player {0} wins!\n".format(board[x]))
                    print("Congratulations!\n")
                    return True
    if 9 == sum((pos == 'X' or pos == 'O') for pos in board):
            print("The game ends in a tie\n")
            return True
def tic_tac_toe():
    board = [None] + list(range(1, 10))
    win = [(1, 2, 3),(4, 5, 6),(7, 8, 9),(1, 4, 7),(2, 5, 8),(3, 6, 9),(1, 5, 9),(3, 5, 7),]
    for player in 'XO' * 9:
            drawboard(board)
            if GO(win,board):
                    break
            print("Player {0}".format(player))
            board[t(board)] = player
            print()
def main():
    while True:
            tic_tac_toe()
            if input("Play again (y/n)\n") != "y":
                    break
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that the code is already a bit messy and still without answer, I would suggest a quick & dirty solution.

You can define a global variable outside of all the functions, like:

```
scoreboard = {"X": 0, "O": 0, "T": 0}
```

Then you simply increment the scores in your `GO` function.

```
def GO(win,board):
    for x, o, b in win:
        if board[x] == board[o] == board[b]:
            print("Player {0} wins!\n".format(board[x]))
            print("Congratulations!\n")
            scoreboard[board[x]] += 1
            return True
    if 9 == sum((pos == 'X' or pos == 'O') for pos in board):
        print("The game ends in a tie\n")
        scoreboard["T"] += 1
        return True
```

And just print the scores from `scoreboard` wherever you want.

However, I would recommend to learn how to make your code more readable. It will help you to write more difficult programs more easily. It will help to avoid quick and dirty solutions like this one and make a lot of difficult things fall into place without much effort.

In any case, congrats on writing a working TTT game, keep it up :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def GO(win,board):
    for x, o, b in win:
        if board[x] == board[o] == board[b]:
            print("Player {0} wins!\n".format(board[x]))
            print("Congratulations!\n")
            return True
    if 9 == sum((pos == 'X' or pos == 'O') for pos in board):
        print("The game ends in a tie\n")
        # return False if there is no winner 
        return False
def tic_tac_toe():
    board = [None] + list(range(1, 10))
    win = [(1, 2, 3),(4, 5, 6),(7, 8, 9),(1, 4, 7),(2, 5, 8),(3, 6, 9),(1, 5, 9),(3, 5, 7),]
    for player in 'XO' * 9:
        drawboard(board)
        if GO(win,board):
            # returns the winner if there is one    
            return player
        elif GO(win, board) is False:
            # returns False if winner is a tie     
            return False  
        print("Player {0}".format(player))
        board[t(board)] = player
        print()
```

First, you should create unique output values for different game outcomes rather than only True. Then, you can keep score in your while loop based on the value of the function call.

```
def main():
   count_x = 0
   count_o = 0 
    while True:
        score = tic_tac_toe()
        if score == 'X':
            count_x += 1
        elif score == 'O':
            count_o += 1 
        print("The running score is " + '('+ str(count_x), str(count_y) +')')
        if input("Play again (y/n)\n") != "y":
            break
main()
```